# How to automatically determine how to crop an image in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing, crop

I am currently making a Discord bot in NodeJS that can process game screenshots as text through OCR. The OCR works fine but one thing is that the user needs to crop the screenshot to a specific window first in order for the bot to be able to read the text without interference from the text outside the window.

For reference, an example game screenshot would be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkE98.jpg) (not necessarily on an emulator)

And the bot only needs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUXxJ.png) part of the image.

Considering that screenshtos can come in different resolutions and aspect ratios, what is a good way to automatically determine how to crop an image like this?

Comment: Check opencv, https://community.risingstack.com/opencv-tutorial-computer-vision-with-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

following npm module use for image cropping :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-clipper

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp